# Background chained ssh tunnel dropped instantly

Tags: ssh, shell, tunnel, reverse-tunnel

I'm trying to establish the following chained ssh tunnel:

```
ssh -A -t gatewayuser@gatewayserver 'ssh -N -A -t -R 55520:127.0.0.1:55520 user@dbserver' &
```

This is part of a shell script, I want the tunnel to be established in the background so the shell script can continue what it is doing. The shell script also uses:

```
trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT
```

To kill all child procs on exit.

When the above ssh runs, a process is established but it seems the chained reverse tunnel is immediately dropped (i.e. there is nothing listening to 55520 on the dbserver). How can I do this within the requirements above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ssh` seems to detect missing user input due to being started in the background and then suspends itself, the `-t` does not help.

You can have it read from stdin instead, e.g. via `ssh [...] < /dev/null &` or possibly `/dev/zero`.

Comment: Do you mean on the chained ssh or the outer one, can you give an example? Sorry if its a dumb question i'm fairly new to all this.

Comment: The outer ssh call, `ssh [..] 'ssh -R [..]' < /dev/null &`